# NSClassFromString() vs classNamed:(NSString *)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dynamic

From what I have read, there seems to be two ways to get an object from a class name. What are the differences between using `NSClassFromString()` and `NSBundle`'s `classNamed:(NSString *)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSClassFromString()` returns a class that has been registered with the runtime for the given name. NSBundle's `classNamed:` returns the class with the given name inside the bundle, which may not have been loaded yet (which means it will load the bundle if necessary).

But a different way: An NSBundle probably does not know about all the classes loaded in your application runtime (though if it's your main bundle, it probably knows about most of your classes). Conversely, your app's runtime will not know about all the classes in a bundle before it is loaded.

Comment: I suspect that `+classNamed:` will cause it to be registered and loaded.

Comment: @bbum: Yeah, it will. Clarified.

Comment: @bbum: `classNamed:` is an instance method (`-classNamed:`), not a class method. That brings me to another difference: Sending `classNamed:` to a bundle is asking *that specific bundle* for the class. If the class is not in that bundle (either because it's in another bundle or because it doesn't exist), you get `Nil`. `NSClassFromString` will return the class no matter what bundle provided it.

Comment: Yah -- right.   I pretty much never use `classNamed:` for several reasons.  Bundles with optionally loaded code are generally a waste of time. Bundle unloading doesn't really work, anyway (is too fragile to be used effectively).  And duplicate classes aren't supported anyway, thus meaning there is no "bundle specific version of class X" anyway.  Better to treat classes as a homogenous part of the runtime, `principalClass` as the "hook" to the bundle, and be done with it.